# AppService Azure Cloud - Force TLS 1.2 outbound - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2, azure-cloud-services

First of all, apologies if my english is not quite correct.

I'm having a problem with the TLS protocol in the Azure cloud.

When I try to make a request to an external web service of the Spanish Tax Agency, it returns the following message: **The request was cancelled: A secure SSL/TLS channel could not be created.**

Testing in a local environment, I solved this with the following statement: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

But the same source code doesn't work in the Azure AppService.

How do I force the protocol for Azure?

I don't have access to a client environment, only the azure portal.

AppService - ASP.NET 4.8 FrameWork 4.5.2

Modify the value of the Web.Config targetFramework field to 4.7.2, but no changes

Comment: The error is due to a timeout that the connection never completed.  Error may or may not be due to TLS failing.  TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is send to establish a secure connection that is encrypted.  The c# library does not have a way of detecting a TLS failure directly so a timeout is used.  You would get same error is service is not running or the URI is bad. Using Net 4.7.,1 or later is recommended because the OS will perform TLS (not Net).

Comment: Error is usually due to one of 3 things if it is a TLS issue 1) Older OS may not support the encryption mode in the certificate 2) The certificate isn't loaded in both the client and server. 3) The certificate is TLS 1.3 and you are only allowing TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments @*jdweng*

> Testing in a local environment, I solved this with the following statement: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; But the same source code doesn't work in the Azure AppService.

***To resolve this, try to upgrade TLS version of your app service manually:***

Go to your `Web App=>settings=>configuration=>General Settings=> Select TLS 1.2` as shown below:

[image]

**Web.Config:**

[image]

***Note:***

- .NET Framewok 4.7 (or) later versions uses the OS settings to determine the default security protocol for SSL/TLS connections.
- As mentioned in the official [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls), it is not best practice to hard code and specify TLS version in .NET framework application.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
Both methods, modifying the information in the Azure portal and modifying both targetframework in the Config, we already put them into practice without result in Azure. Modifying the Web.Config for our local environment did work.